# strange iterator behavior in for loop in g++

Tags: c++, stl

I got this strange issue following is the code snippet which is working properly.

```
std::multimap<long,int>::iterator dateItr = reconnQueueDates.begin();

while( dateItr!=reconnQueueDates.end()  ){
LOG_DEBUG("RUN comparision " <<cDateTime<< ", "<<dateItr->first);
if(dateItr->first <= cDateTime){
    long nextTimeout = -1;
   if( (nextTimeout = callReconnects(dateItr->second,dateItr->first))>-1){

        if(nextTimeout>0){
       reconnQueueDates.insert(std::pair<long , int>(nextTimeout, dateItr->second));
            }
            reconnQueueDates.erase(dateItr);
     LOG_DEBUG("modified the iterator ressetting");
     dateItr = reconnQueueDates.begin();
     LOG_DEBUG("resset iter");
   }//end of callreconnect if
}else{
 ++dateItr;
} //else for datetime check
 }//end of while
```

Before this I was using a for loop with ++dateItr in the loop as follows

```
 for( ;dateItr!=reconnQueueDates.end();++dateItr  ){
LOG_DEBUG("RUN comparision " <<cDateTime<< ", "<<dateItr->first);
if(dateItr->first <= cDateTime){
   long nextTimeout = -1;
   if( (nextTimeout = callReconnects(dateItr->second,dateItr->first))>-1){


            if(nextTimeout>0){
       reconnQueueDates.insert(std::pair<long , int>(nextTimeout, dateItr->second));       
             }
             reconnQueueDates.erase(dateItr);

        LOG_DEBUG("modified the iterator ressetting");
    dateItr = reconnQueueDates.begin();
    LOG_DEBUG("resset iter");
   }// callReconnect 
} // check datetime

 }// for loop
```

While debugging I found out that after changing the map inside the loop the iterator value inside the for construct was still using the old address.

I am using and ubuntu 12.04 with g++ version 4.6.3. Seems to me some kind of compiler bug or some kind of optimization doing this.

Any idea which flag or a bug it might be.

Comment: You'll have to show the complete loop you had before (the one that didn't work). The body you have here isn't compatible with the (incomplete) `for` you have there.

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem?  Is it something to do with the fact that the `reconnQueueDates.insert()` call after the `reconnQueueDates.erase()` call is using an invalidated iterator?

Comment: well there was a bit of logical fault also in the code. But my question was that why was the iterator going into a infinite loop. when using for loop. although i was updating the value of the iterator with map.begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `reconnQueueDates.erase(dateItr);` the iterator in `dateItr` is invalid and any use of it is undefined behaviour. Since both your old and your new `for` loop use it afterwards, the fact that your new version "works" is purely accidental.

The correct way to do it is to first extract all data you might still need (including the position of the next iterator) before erasing that element. For example:

```
std::multimap<long,int>::iterator dateItr = reconnQueueDates.begin();

while( dateItr!=reconnQueueDates.end()  )
{
  LOG_DEBUG("RUN comparision " <<cDateTime<< ", "<<dateItr->first);
  if(dateItr->first <= cDateTime)
  {
    std::multimap<long,int>::iterator nextItr = dateItr;
    ++nextItr;
    long nextTimeout = -1;
    if( (nextTimeout = callReconnects(dateItr->second,dateItr->first))>-1)
    {
      std::pair<long , int> newentry = std::make_pair(nextTimeout, dateItr->second);
      reconnQueueDates.erase(dateItr);
      if(nextTimeout>0)
      {
        reconnQueueDates.insert(newentry);
      }
      LOG_DEBUG("modified the iterator resetting");
      nextItr = reconnQueueDates.begin();
      LOG_DEBUG("reset iter");
    }//end of callreconnect if
    dateItr = nextItr;
  }
  else
  {
    ++dateItr;
  } //else for datetime check
}//end of while
```

Comment: Sidenote: Since C++11 std::multimap.erase will return an iterator, so "nextItr = reconnQueueDates.erase(dateItr);" saves some overhead.